# SQL Server: Read .ldf files

Tags: sql-server

Is there a free tool to read .ldf (Sql server database transaction log files) files ?

Thanks in advance,

Albert

Answer (score 1):

I know of a couple of options, unfortunately I don't know of any free ones, but many offer free trials if your just looking to do something as a one off:

- [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm) - has a 14 day trial but is only for SQL 2000 (you don't state what version you are looking at)
- [Apex SQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.asp)

Answer (score 1):

There's an undocumented command which allows you to query a transaction log.

http://killspid.blogspot.com/2006/07/using-fndblog.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SQL Log Rescue http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/index.htm

Comment: Just bear in mind this is only for SQL 2000

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

There are undocumented command such as fn_dblog() and DBCC LOG that will give you a dump of SQL Server log transactions, although don't expect to see nicely formatted DDL/DML.

There are products (not free) which can be used to reconstruct the log output into T-SQL.  They are:

- ApexSQL Log
- SQL Log Rescue
- Log Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Try [Free SQL LDF File Viewer](http://www.mdfviewer.com/ldf/) which allow you to read and analyze SQL Server Transaction logs.